# Accessing PHP variable references outside the local scope

Tags: php, class, hook, eval

(If you fancy a good challenge. Vote this question up.)

Dear stackoverflow fellows. I wanna provide a brilliant way for hooks/extensions.

I have a problem accessing variable references outside a class or function.

Problematics:

1. I don't want to turn local variables to globals. If they are local they should stay local.
2. I don't know what variables the hook-developer wants to access so I can't pass any selected variable references to the hook.
3. The hook is only able to access globals nested outside itself, which makes it worthless to call a hook in a parent local scope.

A static dummy-hook example (without any dynamics):

```
<?php
  class hook {
    function before_process() {
      global $couldbeanything;
      $couldbeanything = 'hello dummy';
    }
  }
?>
```

Works in the global scope:

```
<?php
  $couldbeanything = 'hello world';
  $hook = new hook;      
  $hook->before_process();
  echo $couldbeanything;
?>
```

Doesn't work in a function (local scope):

```
<?php
  function foobar() {
    $couldbeanything = 'hello world';
    $hook = new hook;      
    $hook->before_process();
    echo $couldbeanything;
  }
  foobar();
?>
```

I practically need something like this inside the hook (if there was such a thing):

```
parent $couldbeanything;
```

or

```
outer $couldbeanything;
```

The only solution I can come up with is the same that PunBB uses, eval(php_code_from_an_xml_doc). It has disadvantages as well. Without stating what outer references you wanna access, you can accidentally overwrite variables by the same name. Also, XML formated PHP code which is evaluated is kind of tacky to debug.

Who is the smartest guy in here with a solution better than eval().

Maybe these are some tools for ideas: get_defined_vars, extract, pass-by-reference, call_user_func

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to find local variables from outside the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Who here can so far come up with a solution better than this? It doesn't use references but variable duplicates. But it's close enough and eliminates the need of eval() for hooks in a nested variable scope.

```
<?php
  class hook {
    function before_process($args) {
      extract($args);

      $couldbeanything = 'good bye world';

      return compact('couldbeanything');
    }
  }

  function foobar() {
    $couldbeanything = 'hello world';

    $hook = new hook;
    extract($hook->before_process(get_defined_vars()), EXTR_OVERWRITE);

    echo $couldbeanything;
  }
  foobar();
?>
```

See the hook class, and how I execute the hook inside foobar().

Answer (score -1):

Using your sample functions, I was able to get hook->before_process() to modify the $couldbeanything variable - even when it was called from within the foobar() function.  Was that your goal?

```
$couldbeanything=NULL;

class hook {
    function before_process() {
      global $couldbeanything;
      $couldbeanything = 'hello dummy';
    }
  }


  function foobar() {
      global $couldbeanything;
    $couldbeanything = 'hello world';
    $hook=new hook;
    $hook->before_process();
    echo $couldbeanything;
  }
  foobar();
```

This returns 'hello dummy'.

The key is to make $couldbeanything a global variable within the foobar() function - that way both that function and the before_process() function within the hook class are modifying the same global variable.

The other option, if you want to retain both values, is to make $couldbeanything an array.

$couldbeanything=NULL;

```
class hook {
    function before_process() {
      global $couldbeanything;
      $couldbeanything['hook'] = 'hello dummy';
    }
  }


  function foobar() {
      global $couldbeanything;
    $couldbeanything['foobar'] = 'hello world';
    $hook=new hook;
    $hook->before_process();
    echo'Foobar is "'.$couldbeanything['foobar'].'", while Hook is "'.$couldbeanything['hook'].'".';
  }
  foobar();
```

This returns 'Foobar is "hello world", while Hook is "hello dummy".'

Otherwise, to not change the global variable, this would work:

```
$couldbeanything='Original Value';

class hook {
    function before_process() {
      global $couldbeanything;
      $newValue=$couldbeanything.' - added value';
      return $newValue;
    }
  }


  function foobar() {
    $couldbeanything = 'hello world';
    $hook=new hook;
    $newValue=$hook->before_process();
    echo'The local value is "'.$couldbeanything.'", while the hook modified value is "'.$newValue.'". ';
  }
  foobar();
echo'Global value is "'.$couldbeanything.'"';
```

This would return 'The local value is "hello world", while the hook modified value is "Original Value - added value". Global value is "Original Value"'

Comment: You are changing a variable in the global scope that way. The solution I am looking for is to avoid that. I can't rewrite all functions in the framework to all use their local variables globally. A framework is already written, we're looking for ways to override variables by hooking some logic.

Comment: Changed it to not modify the original, global value. Would that work?

Comment: No sorry, I think you are missing the point. We want the hook to override the core functions. Not to change the core functions.